# C# Automation: Execute specific rows from CSV file

Tags: c#, automation

Currently sm using CSV file to read data from, I need to read specific row and continue executing script, below is what I tried to do so far,

```
C# Code: DataRow specificRow = TestContext.DataRow.Table.Rows[2];
```

I get mentioned row data to "specificRow", all good in reading, but the script is executing three times since it starts from 0, and executes same row all the time.

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
data1   DataA   DataAlpha   TestData
data2   DataA   DataBeta    TestData
data3   DataA   DataAlpha   TestData
data4   DataA   DataAB  TestData
```

How can I execute the row only once?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What script is executing three times? From where are you calling it? What starts from 0. If you have a fixed index in your code, how is it supposed to return something else then the third row?

Comment: Apologies! Any script if I run executes three times if the index is "2", from the testMethod I`m calling it, the iteration starts from 0 and stops at "2". Editting the question.